# How to control the timing of shell execution in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am having the following directory structure:

```
/CMakeLists.txt
/component-a/CMakeLists.txt
           /...
/component-b/CMakeLists.txt
           /...
/doc/CMakeLists.txt
```

In the top CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(component-a)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(component-b)
```

In the sub dir(component-a/component-b) CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(xxx SHARED ${xxx})
```

this commond will link some c and h files which will generate by other tools

now I want to exec shell in the top  CMakeLists.txt after the build of this two sub dir.

how can I write execute_process/add_custom_command/add_custom_target

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `execute_process`, as it runs things at the configuration stage.

Second, you can define the execution order by properly setting dependencies between targets using `add_dependencies()`.

Comment: thinks for your answer.